# Question about normal subgroups and cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have seen two definitions of a normal subgroup. The first one:

> A subgroup $N$ is normal to a group $G$ if $xN = Nx$, $\forall x \in G$

The second one:

> $N$ is normal to a group $G$ if $N \diagdown G = G \diagup N$ - that is, if the set of left cosets equal the set of right cosets.

I'm wondering if it is possible to have  say $ G = \{ 1,x,y,....x^my \}$ and a subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $xN = Ny$, but $N \diagdown G = G \diagup N$. Surely such an example would show that the two definitions are not equivalent, right?

Comment: Pick a left coset $xN$. It contains $x$. If it is also a right coset, that right coset *must* be $Nx$ because the only right coset containing $x$ is $Nx$. Thus $xN = Nx$. The point is that while lots of different elements can lie in a left coset of a subgroup $N$, *any* one of them can be used to produce the coset, i.e., if $g \in hN$ then $gN = hN$, and likewise for right cosets.

Comment: okay i think i got it thanks

Comment: @KCd Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Meelo, KCd rarely posts answers, but you could write up KCd's answer and post it yourself (giving the appropriate attribution, of course). Even better, we could both encourage OP to write up and post a solution, now that OP knows how to do the problem.

Comment: Any takers? Anyone want to post the KCd comment as an answer? @Meelo? OP?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, since the set of left cosets and the set of right cosets each form a partition of the group; thus, we can say:

> If cosets $xN$ and $yN$ have a non-empty intersection, then $xN=yN$.

However, if the set of left and right cosets are equal, as in the second definition you give of a normal subgroup, then we can extend that to

> If cosets $xN$ and $Ny$ have a non-empty intersection, then $xN=Ny$.

since the set of subsets of the form $yN$ and of the form $Ny$ are equal by hypothesis. However, given that $x$ is a member of both $xN$ and $Nx$, it holds that those two cosets have non-empty intersection and are thus equal.